# Extract multiple polygon coordinates of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, polygon

I want to extract the (multiple) polygon coordinates of a .xlsx file into Panda Dataframe in Python.

The .xlsx file is available on [google docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oel5q0zJafWCbMtkh9Tp8YhbEdID36LbpzBS8XuLfZM/edit#gid=0).

Now I do this:

```
import pandas as pd  

gemeenten2019 = pd.read_excel('document.xlsx', index=False, skiprows=0 )
gemeenten2019['KML'] = str(gemeenten2019['KML'])

for index, row in gemeenten2019.iterrows():
    removepart = str(row['KML'])
    row['KML'] = removepart.replace('<MultiGeometry><Polygon><coordinates>', '')

gemeentenamen = []
gemeentePolygon = []

for gemeentenaam in gemeenten2019['NAAM']:
    gemeentenamen.append(str(gemeentenaam))

for value in gemeenten2019['KML']:
    gemeentePolygon.append(str(value))


df_gemeenteCoordinaten = pd.DataFrame({'Gemeente':gemeentenamen, 'KML': gemeentePolygon})
df_gemeenteCoordinaten
```

But the result is that every column ("KML") has the same results.

[image: result]

Only I want the coordinates for that specific row his column and not all the coordinates of all the columns.

The dataframe must look like:

[image: this]

Does anyone know how to extract the multiple coordinates for each row?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide your results and desired output as code fences, not images. You should provide a few data points (say five) as well and put the link to the full data additionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you each pair of values on its own line:

```
import pandas as pd  

gemeenten2019 = pd.read_excel('Gemeenten 2019.xlsx', index=False, skiprows=0)
gemeenten2019['KML'] = gemeenten2019['KML'].str.strip('<>/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzGMP').str.replace(' ', '\n')
```

For example:

```
                    NAAM                                                KML
0            Aa en Hunze  6.81394482119469,53.070971596018\n6.8612875225...
1               Aalsmeer  4.79469736599488,52.2606817589009\n4.795085405...
2                 Aalten  6.63891586106867,51.9625470164657\n6.639463741...
3          Achtkarspelen  6.23217311778447,53.2567474241222\n6.235100748...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need. :)